Flutter use Firebase Storage resize image extension correclty
I would like to use the Resize Images Extension in my Firebase app, but currently always get a 403 code if I want to display the images.
This is what I am currently doing in my Flutter app:

Save image as byteList in Storage
Retrieve url with getDownloadUrl
Store downloadUrl in Firebase Firestore

And then I can simply display the images in my app via a Image.network(item.downloadUrl).
Problem:
I just tried to install the extension mentioned above. I configured it so it's replacing the old image with the resized one, and also I did not make the image public.
But now I am getting a permission denied 403, when trying to display the images with the saved downloadUrl.
Does the url change? Or maybe the token? How can I use the extension while still displaying the images with downloadUrl?
Let me know if you need any more information!

You should show all relevant code that doesn't work the way you expect, along with your debugging information.   A simple numbered list of things you're doing doesn't tell us if you might be doing something wrong.  We should be able to copy your code and follow your instructions to reproduce the same behavior.

@DougStevenson that was on purpose, because I thought this is a more general question, and not really code specific.
I think adding code to each steps would just make it more complicated :D  No?

If you don't show your code, then what are we supposed to use to determine what generates that error and what to do to resolve it?  On Stack Overflow, it's expected that questions provide a complete minimal reproducible example. Without it, the question could be closed as needing debugging details.

I've left a comment with a potential solution, hope it helps!
I'm curious; how did you set up the extension to replace the original image with the resized one? I'm interested in achieving the same thing, but didn't think that'd be possible with the extension. Thanks!

There are two options of the Extension that sound like they could cause this:

Make resized images public
Do you want to make the resized images public automatically? So you can access them by URL.


Assign new access token
Should resized images have a new access token assigned to them, different from the original image?

I would begin by ensuring Make resized images public is TRUE. If so, then I'd investigate if the new access token assignment is correctly configured.
